# Selecting specific distinct column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a select statement so that it does a specific distinct on one column. I am trying to make it so that there is not multiple fruits within each id. If there is multiple fruits under an id, I would like use only 1 approved fruit, over the rotten fruit. If there is only 1 fruit under that id, use it.

```
SELECT id, fruit, fruitweight, status 
  FROM myfruits
```

```
Raw data from current select    

    id |  fruit  | fruitweight | status
    1  |  apple  |      .2     | approved
    1  |  apple  |      .8     | approved
    1  |  apple  |      .1     | rotten
    1  |  orange |      .5     | approved
    2  |  grape  |      .1     | rotten
    2  |  orange |      .7     | approved
    2  |  orange |      .5     | approved
```

How it should be formatted after constraint

```
    id |  fruit  | fruitweight | status
    1  |  apple  |      .2     | approved
    1  |  orange |      .5     | approved
    2  |  grape  |      .1     | rotten
    2  |  orange |      .7     | approved
```

I can do something along the lines of `select distinct id,fruit,fruitweight,status from myfruits`,
but that will only take out the duplicates if all columns are the same.

Comment: Why do different fruits have the same ID?

Comment: *will only take out the duplicates if all columns are the same* - that **IS** the way `DISTINCT` works - as designed

Comment: How do you chose that apple row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CTE with aggregate and row_number.

```
declare @YourTable table (id int, fruit varchar(64), fruitweight decimal(2,1),status varchar(64))
insert into @YourTable
values
(1,'apple',0.2,'approved'),
(1,'apple',0.8,'approved'),
(1,'apple',0.1,'rotten'),
(1,'orange',0.5,'approved'),
(2,'grape',0.1,'rotten'),
(2,'orange',0.7,'approved'),
(2,'orange',0.5,'approved')


;with cte as(
select
    id
    ,fruit
    ,fruitweight = min(fruitweight)
    ,[status]
    ,RN = row_number() over (partition by id, fruit order by case when status = 'approved' then 1 else 2 end)
from 
    @YourTable
group by
    id,fruit,status)

select
    id
    ,fruit
    ,fruitweight
    ,status
from
    cte
where RN = 1
```

Another method, without the aggregate... assuming you want the *first* fruightweight

```
;with cte as(
select
    id
    ,fruit
    ,fruitweight 
    ,[status]
    ,RN = row_number() over (partition by id, fruit order by case when status = 'approved' then 1 else 2 end, fruitweight)
from 
    @YourTable)

select
    id
    ,fruit
    ,fruitweight
    ,status
from
    cte
where RN = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is using the **WITH TIES** clause.

**Example**

```
Select top 1 with ties *
 From  YourTable 
 Order By Row_Number() over (Partition By id,fruit order by status,fruitweight)
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need to also order by fruitweight or suffer potentially inconsistent results?  notice apple is listed twice with the same status approved.  which one do we pick?

Comment: @xQbert Perhaps.  But OP made no mention of fruitweight.  I will add just in case.

Answer (score 1):

A shorter version of scsimon's solution without aggregates.
If you have SQL Server < 2012, you'll have to use case instead of iif.

```
select
    id
    ,fruit
    ,fruitweight
    ,status
from 
(
    select
        id
        ,fruit
        ,fruitweight
        ,status
        ,rownum         = row_number() over(partition by id, fruit order by iif(status = 'approved', 0, 1), fruitweight desc)
    from myfruits
) x
where rownum = 1
```

**EDIT**: I started writing before scsimon edited his post to included a version without aggregates...

Comment: No need to explain that you posted while I answered. You used a method that I did not! Good idea! +1 from me.